# Selecting random columns for each group of pyspark RDD/dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

My dataframe as got 10,0000 columns, I have to apply some logic on each group (key is region and dept). Each group will use max 30 columns from 10k columns, the 30 columns list is from the second data set column "colList". Each group will have 2-3 millions rows. My approach is to do group by key and call function like below. But it fails - 1. shuffle and 2.data group is more than 2G(can be solved by re-partition but its costly), 3. very slow

```
def testfunc(iter):
   <<got some complex business logic which cant be done in spark API>>

resRDD = df.rdd.groupBy(region, dept).map(lambda x: testfunc(x))
```

Input:

```
region dept week val0 val1  val2  val3 ... val10000   
 US    CS   1     1    2    1     1   ...  2 
 US    CS   2     1.5  2    3     1   ...  2
 US    CS   3     1    2    2     2.1      2
 US    ELE  1     1.1  2    2     2.1      2
 US    ELE  2     2.1  2    2     2.1      2
 US    ELE  3     1    2    1     2   .... 2
 UE    CS   1     2    2    1     2   .... 2
```

Columns to pick for each group: (data set 2)

```
region dept colList   
 US    CS   val0,val10,val100,val2000 
 US    ELE  val2,val5,val800,val900
 UE    CS   val21,val54,val806,val9000
```

My second solution is  create a new data set from input data with only 30 columns and rename the columns to col1 to col30. Then use a mapping list for each columns and group. Then i can apply groupbyKey (assuming), which will be Skinner than original input of 10K columns.

```
region dept week col0 col1  col2  col3 ... col30   
 US    CS   1     1    2    1     1   ...  2 
 US    CS   2     1.5  2    3     1   ...  2
 US    CS   3     1    2    2     2.1      2
 US    ELE  1     1.1  2    2     2.1      2
 US    ELE  2     2.1  2    2     2.1      2
 US    ELE  3     1    2    1     2   .... 2
 UE    CS   1     2    2    1     2   .... 2
```

Can any one help to convert Input with 10K to  30 columns? Or any other alternative should be fine to avoid group by.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the create_map function to convert all the 10k columns to map per row. Now use a UDF which takes the map, region and dept and dillutes the map to the 30 columns and make sure to always have the same names for all 30 columns. 
Lastly you can wrap your complex function to receive the map instead of the original 10K columns. Hopefully this will get it small enough to work properly.

If not, you can get a distinct of region and dept and assuming there are few enough you can loop through one and groupby the other.

Comment: Thanks Assaf, Yes i am following the same, created a map dict and created 30 columns which is same for all combinations. I cant loop because i have 2K combinations. Each loop will not use entire cluster. One problem with map each row is it is taking 30 mins for 5M rows. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you can share your code I can try to figure out something.